# Contact Form (SimpleForm) - Route not found/unable to autoload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to install the contact page on my Ruby on Rails app. It seems straight forward enough, but after installing the mailer gems, and creating my controller with:

`$ rails generate controller contact_form new create`

I navigate to my contact URL (/contact_form/new), and it says

> "Unable to autoload constant ContactFormController, expected
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/contact_form_controller.rb to
>   define it"

Routes and controller are as follows:

**routes.rb**

```
get 'contact_form/new'
get 'contact_form/create'
resources :contact_forms
```

**contact_form_controller.rb**

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new
    end

    def create
      begin
        @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form])
        @contact_form.request = request
        if @contact_form.deliver
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
        else
          render :new
        end
      rescue ScriptError
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry, this message appears to be spam and was not delivered.'
      end
    end
  end
```

**contact_form.rb**

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "your_email@example.org",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your class is named `ContactFormsController` and Rails is looking for `ContactFormController`. You need to pay careful attention to the pluralization in Rails.

- Controllers are plural.
- Models are singular.
- Routes are plural in most cases.
- The pluralization of classes must always match the file name.

So why is Rails looking for `ContactFormController`? Because your routes are not defined properly:

```
get 'contact_form/new'
get 'contact_form/create'
```

`get 'contact_forms/new'` is the proper route for a form to create a new resource. You don't create resources with GET so get rid of `get 'contact_form/create'`.

```
resources :contact_forms
```

Is actually [all that you need](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

So to fix this error you should:

1. rename `contact_form_controller.rb` -> `contact_forms_controller.rb`.
2. change your route definition.
3. request `/contact_forms/new` instead.

Comment: Made your changes, but now I get "uninitialized constant ContactFormsController::ContactForm" for this line: @contact_form = ContactForm.new Do I need to pluralize contact_forms everywhere now then? Tried it and I still get the same error.

Comment: No - models should be in singular. You can get around the error with  `@contact_form = ::ContactForm.new` - not quite sure why rails is treating your controller as a namespace which is odd.

Comment: No dice - changed that line and I still get: uninitialized constant ContactForm

Comment: You do have a `app/models/contact_form.rb` which declares the class `ContactForm`?

Comment: I did not - I thought it was created automatically. Just added it (see edits above). Though now I get this error, and I know my templates are there?  Missing template contact_forms/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"

Comment: Well you need to have the parts line up. Rails won't generate models when you run `rails generate controller contact_form new create` and the view is probably named `contact_form/new.html.erb` instead of `contact_forms/new.html.rb`